# Checking if a cell value exists in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the misleading title, hopefully my explanation helps you understand what I want.

I have three columns:

```
   A             B                  C
  SKU      media_gallery       image_paths
LNH222A                    +/JPEG/LNH222A-5.jpg
LNH222B                    +/JPEG/LNH222A-8-ROOM.jpg
                           +/JPEG/LNH222B-5.jpg
                           +/JPEG/LNH222B-6R.jpg 
                                  ....
```

I want to check if a cell's value within column A exists somehwere in a cell's value of column C, and if so put the matching column C cell into column B parallel to the matching string. So if `LNH222A` exists somewhere in column C, take that matched cell value and place it into column B.

So in the example above, cell B2 should have the value of:

`+/JPEG/LNH222A-5.jpg+/JPEG/LNH222A-8-ROOM.jpg`

The same would happen for `LNH222B` and so on ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that your data begins in row #2:

```
Sub Adrift()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = Cells(I, "A").Value
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(Cells(J, "C").Value, v) > 0 Then
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: **Please test the changes I just made.**